# Regular Expression or Not (Getting not all text that satisfies regexp)

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I want use regex to find something in string (or QString) that is between " (quotes).

My simple String:  x="20.51167"  and I want 20.51167.

Is it possible with Regular Expressions ??

On start I had somthing like this string :

`<S id="1109" s5="1" nr="1183" n="Some text" test="          " x="20.53843" y="50.84443">`

Using regexp like: `(nr=\"[0-9]+\")` `(y=\"[0-9 .^\"]+\")"` `etc` I get my simple string like x="20.51167". Maybe this is wrong way and I can get value that is between quotes at one time ??

Comment: Also, the obligatory comment about not trying to parse XML/HTML using regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/183339. Can you use QXmlStreamReader?

Comment: @DaveMateer I think it's not neccesary to use QXmlStreamReader :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular example, this will work:

```
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    //Here's your regexp.
    QRegExp re("\"[^\"^=]+\"");
    //Here's your sample string:
    QString test ="<S id=\"1109\" s5=\"1\" nr=\"1183\" n=\"Some text\" test=\" \" x=\"20.53843\" y=\"50.84443\">";
    int offset = 0;
    while( offset = re.indexIn( test, offset + 1 ) )
    {
        if(offset == -1)
            break;
        QString res = re.cap().replace("\"", "");
        bool ok;
        int iRes;
        float fRes;
        if( res.toInt( &ok ) && ok )
        {
            iRes = res.toInt();
            std::cout << "int: " << iRes << std::endl;
        }
        else if ( res.toFloat( &ok ) && ok )
        {
            fRes = res.toFloat();
            std::cout << "float: " << fRes << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "string: " << res.toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output will be;

```
int: 1109
int: 1
int: 1183
string: Some text
string:  
float: 20.5384
float: 50.8444
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output still has quotes. My next step will be changing  output to strings or ints or doubles and put these to database. So I need output without quotes and I need to know what is what (that is the reason that I made different regexp for each one.

Comment: @poplawskidaniel, It has quotes because it's a list of QStrings. Convert them to appropriate types with QString's methods (e.g. `toFloat()`) methods, and you're done.

Comment: It has quotes inside, so converting using `ToInt()`, `ToFloat()` etc not working (always return 0). Try it.

Comment: it's not exacly what I want but it's effective. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this works. **untested**

```
="([^"]+)"
```

The above captures anything that is in-between `="`  `"`

Comment: unfortunately this also capture =" " signs. Using QRegExp class and QString.contains

Answer (score 1):

In this expression : (nr=\"[0-9]+\") (y=\"[0-9 .^\"]+\")"
Delete the last quote after )

For your regular expression try :

x=^[0-9]+.[0-9]{5}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find anything in quotes, I guess the regex should read:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

(anything that is not a quote between quotes)

Comment: like answer above: this also capture " " signs.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move your capturing group *inside* the quotes:

```
x=\"([0-9.]+)\"
```